# Clicking a button on a web page already open

Tags: python, google-chrome

I am trying to write a Python code to click a button and do stuff on a chrome tab already open.
I know how to use selenium to open a new web page but due to credentials issues, i need my users to open the web page before they run the script.

How can this be done?

Comment: Hello, can you please share the code you already wrote?

Comment: I think Selenium can't control browser opened by someone else.